# Convert QByteArray to std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, vector, std, unsigned-char, qbytearray

I tried to convert `QByteArray` to `std::vector<unsigned char>` using this code:

```
unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)byteArrayBuffer.constData();
std::vector<unsigned char>::size_type size = strlen((const char*)buffer);
std::vector<unsigned char> bufferToCompress(buffer, buffer + size);
```

but, assuming that `byteArrayBuffer` is a `QByteArray` filled with data, I think it doesn't work well on line `unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)byteArrayBuffer.constData();` because `byteArrayBuffer.size()` returns a different value than `bufferToCompress.size()`.

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Qt, but surely you just want

```
std::vector<unsigned char> bufferToCompress(
    byteArrayBuffer.begin(), byteArrayBuffer.end());
```

<sub>Note: `strlen` is not particularly useful in C++; it tells you the length of a C-style null-terminated string (by searching memory until it either finds either finds a zero-valued byte, or falls off the end of accessible memory and crashes), but can't tell you the size of an array, which is what you'd need here. Also, using evil C-style casts to force invalid code to compile is never a good idea.</sub>

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I'm fairly sure this will work, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As I see here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html QByteArray does not have begin/end methods. But have data/length. Result code may be looks like this:

```
const unsigned char* begin = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(byteArrayBuffer.data());
const unsigned char* end = begin + byteArrayBuffer.length();
std::vector<unsigned char> bufferToCompress( begin, end );
```

Comment: It's odd that `begin` and `end` seem to be undocumented; they certainly [exist](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/68fb37d762a818cc44ea69f7c3a80a3f010b6713:src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h#L362).